# How to store a "location" for an "event" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

I have two entities: **Event** and **Location**. The relations are:

**1 Event** can have **1 Location**.
**1 Location** can have **many Events**.

Basically I want to store events. And each event is hosted in a specific location. When I say specific location I mean:

```
Street, Number, City, Zip Code, State, Country
```

I basically have a design question, that I would like some help with:

1 - Right now I am thinking on doing the following:

Event table will have a `location_id` that will point to a specific location row in the locations table.  What happens with this is that:
I will have many repeated values in each row. For example, if an event is happening in **356** Matilda Street in San Francisco, and another one is happening in **890** Matilda Street in San Francisco. The values Matilda Street and San Francisco will be **duplicated** many times in the location table.  How can I redesign that to normalize this?

So, basically I would love to hear a good approach to solve this question in terms of a relational database, like MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a strictly normalized database, you could have a table for street names, another for cities, another for states, and so on.  You might even have an additional `location` table that holds unique combinations of street, city, and state; you'd add rows to this table each time an event occurs at a previously unknown location.  Then each of your events would reference the appropriate row in the `location` table.

In practice, though, it's sometimes better simply to store the location data directly within the `events` table and tolerate the extra memory usage; there's always a trade-off between speed and memory use.

Another consideration: what happens if a street is renamed?  Do you want old events to be associated with the old name or the new name?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would love to rename the street for old events. I am also thinking that if I put the location inside the events table, I am restricting myself to, for example, add a new field in the location table that would say the specific location, like "Giants Stadium".

Answer (score 1):

Each location in the `locations` table should be uniquely identifiable by its `PRIMARY KEY`.  Records in the `events` table then reference their associated location with column(s) that contain the value of that `PRIMARY KEY`.

For example, your locations table might contain:

```
location_id | Street         | Number | City          | Zip Code | State | Country
------------+----------------+--------+---------------+----------+-------+---------
          1 | Matilda Street |    356 | San Francisco |    12345 | CA    | USA
          2 | Matilda Street |    890 | San Francisco |    12345 | CA    | USA
```

Then your `events` table might contain:

```
event_id | location_id | Date       | Description
---------+-------------+------------+----------------
       1 |           1 | 2012-04-28 | Birthday party
       2 |           1 | 2012-04-29 | Hangover party
       3 |           2 | 2012-04-29 | Funeral
       4 |           1 | 2012-05-01 | May day!
```

In this example, `location_id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` in the `locations` table and a `FOREIGN KEY` in the `events` table.

Comment: This is what I am doing, and I appreciate your answer. However, this doesn't answer the normalization doubt that I am having. Would you be fine with having San Francisco repeated multiple times in the location table?

Comment: Apologies, in my haste I had misunderstood your question.  @AdamLiss's answer addresses those concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Your Locations table should have a unique ID such as 1=Matilda Street, 2=Market Street - one record for each possible location NO DUPLICATES, then your Events table should have a location ID that uses one of those IDs - again, one for each event, no duplicate.

You can then join them like this;

```
SELECT events.event_name, locations.location_name
FROM events
JOIN locations on locations.location_id = events.location_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplication is very normal because each of them is an unique location. And beyond that, the design you think is very usable when you try to filter the places in san francisco.